# Area 51 - Warn users of related closed proposals

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, closed-proposals

I'm writing this after my own experience with a [closed proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34369/flight-simulation).

When a user creates a new proposal on Area 51, they are warned of related proposals that they might be duplicating. The same happens with questions on stack exchange.

Why doesn't it warn you of previously closed proposals? - In a way that would be more valuable.

If as you started typing the name, and it came up with a list of related closed proposals, and why they were closed, that would be very useful. It would prevent users from creating proposals that were instantly closed, when they could have realised before.

A problem that could occur is that users delete their closed proposals, or they simply get left, and then cleaned up. A way around this would just be to store whenever a closed proposal is deleted, or cleaned up, and then for this to be searched when a user starts typing a new proposal name.

If you have any ideas related to this please say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good idea. We always showed closed proposals in the "related proposals" list, but now we include the closed reasons as well, and emphasize closed proposals in the UI:

[image: before/after screenshots]

Comment: interesting - when I first created my proposal that was closed because another one had already been closed, it didn't show up in there, there was only one suggested proposal, which was open, and not a duplicate of mine

Comment: I see your [Flight Simulation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34369/flight-simulation) proposal -- which is the other closed proposal it's a duplicate of?

Comment: it got removed in cleanup

Comment: Hiding deleted proposals from the list is actually by design. Most deleted proposals, including [the one in question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30042), are deleted by mods as part of periodic cleanup. They typically aren't deleted because the proposal is inherently flawed, but rather because that specific proposal will probably never gather the momentum necessary to advance to the next phase. In other words, they might succeed if re-created. (Some closed proposals, on the other hand, are left open to serve as warnings that similar proposals not be created.)

Comment: If it was open and deleted, then that shouldn't appear on the list. But don't you think if it was closed, left for a bit, then deleted, it should appear on the list of related closed proposals? - this was the case I encountered.

Comment: *Some closed proposals, on the other hand, are left open to serve as warnings that similar proposals not be created.* Emmett, that may have been the case at one point, but not any longer; everything gets deleted eventually. @Alex, the difference between closed and deleted is that the latter no longer show up in searches. Saying that they *should* show up is the same as saying that they should not be deleted.

Comment: @Dori - If something is closed and then deleted (automatically) - surely people should be warned not to create a related proposal?

Comment: @Alex - to the best of my knowledge, there are no automatic deletions—they're all done manually.